# Good introductory books on dilation theories?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, textbook-recommendation

Are there any good introductory type of books that contain dilation theories of Sz-Nagy, Rohlin and Akcoglu?

Comment: Could you try to narrow down what you are looking for? I am aware of the Nagy dilation theorem but I don't really know what "dilation theory of Nagy" is supposed to be

Comment: Yes, that's the one I was referring to: Sz-Nagy dilation.

Answer (score 2):

The following very readable book should be of interest to you:

V. Paulsen. ["*Completely bounded maps and operator algebras*"](http://www.cambridge.org/9780521816694). Cambridge University Press (2003).

Answer (score 2):

Apart from Paulsen's book on completely bounded maps you may find *Harmonic Analysis of Operators on Hilbert Space* by Sz.-Nagy, C. Foias, H. Bercovici & L. Kérchy interesting. It should cover most of Sz.-Nagy's work.

A nice exposition of the the Akcoglu-Sucheston dilation theorem (with full proofs) can be found in G. Fendler's lecture notes [On Dilations and Transference for Continuous One-Parameter Semigroups of Positive Contractions on Lp-spaces](http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.5425)